# correlation reference and skipped block in SQL

Tags: sql, subquery, amazon-redshift, correlated-subquery

I'm having trouble to understand the following phrase, from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_correlated_subqueries.html.

`the block containing the correlation reference and the skipped block are connected by a NOT EXISTS predicate`

So what is the "correlation reference" and "skipped block" in the following SQL?

```
select event.eventname from event
where not exists
(select * from listing
where not exists
(select * from sales where event.eventid=sales.eventid));
```

Comment: the listing table has no use... perhaps you want to expound OP for better understanding

Comment: As @maSTAShuFu is implying, the listing table is a skipped block. The query can be rewritten as `select eventname from event where not exists (select * from sales where event.eventid = sales.eventid)` and the listing block is skipped.